# Nuget package only works with default solution configuration

Tags: visual-studio, nuget

Using visual studio 2015, when I install a library with Nuget Package Manager everything works fine on Release and/or Debug, but not any other configuration.

Any configuration named something other than the default configuration names results in LNK2019 unresolved external symbol. Even if I make a new solution configuration and that I copy settings from Release or Debug (and change nothing else), I will still get the same problem.

I saw someone with a similar problem here: https://github.com/Microsoft/cpprestsdk/issues/124 who commented:

> I had a similar issue and the cause is that my build configurations
>   are not named "Debug" and "Release". If your configs are named
>   otherwise, the linker will fail. **To fix this you can just add your
>   build config names to the targets file in the package directory**.
>
> I don't know if this is something that can be fixed or if it's a known
>   limtiation of VS/Nuget, but it would have been helpful to have a note
>   or something on the tutorial page.

Problem is: I don't know how to do what I put in bold, even after googling extensively.

Comment: Which NuGet package do you install in your project? I added an opencv native package for my C++ project, no matter I change the Solution Configuration as Debug/Release or other custom Solution Configuration, the project could be compiled successful. Please share the detailed steps to help us reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to the packages folder where you installed the nuget package (It is usually in the same path with your solution file), you should see the several folders for "cpprestsdk". Open the one you are using with your project, for example: "cpprestsdk.v120.winphone.msvcstl.dyn.rt-dyn.2.9.1" and then open the "build" and then "native" folder in it, you will see the target file with .targets extension:

> cpprestsdk.v120.winphone.msvcstl.dyn.rt-dyn.targets

Edit this file and add your configuration.